# problem with siunitx package in IEEEaccess template

Tags: ieeeaccess

Whenever I insert the command `\usepackage{siunitx}` in my `IEEEaccess` template document, I get the error `\begin{document}` missing.

How can I define units in my article if `siunitx` is not recognized?

My MWE (copied from comment):

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\EOD 
\end{document}
```

And this is my log file:

```latex
Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.7598 ...onst:Nn \c_sys_year_int  { \tex_year:D }
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.7598 ...onst:Nn \c_sys_year_int  { \tex_year:D }
                                                  
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
You can't use `\numexpr' in vertical mode.

\int_compare:nNnTF ...nt_eval:w #1#2\__int_eval:w 
                                                  #3\__int_eval_end: \exp_af...
l.7598 ...onst:Nn \c_sys_year_int  { \tex_year:D }
                                                  
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

No \begin{document} command was found. Make sure you have included \begin{document} in your preamble, and that your main document is set correctly.

Was this hint helpful?Yes / No
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7598 ...onst:Nn \c_sys_year_int  { \tex_year:D }
                                                  
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Did you really use `\includepackage{siunitx}` or `\usepackage{siunitx}`? The latter would be correct.

Comment: Thank you! I just checked, I actually used \usepackage....

Comment: I will edit the answer, so sorry for the mistake

Comment: Please provide some small document example (MWE), which reproduce your problem. For example, the following work as expected: `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <--- had to be loaded
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\SI{1}{\kilo\metre}
\EOD
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko This is a small example to try in the ieeeaccess template '\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

    
\begin{document}

\EOD

\end{document}'

Comment: @Wallflower Please edit the original post.

Comment: @ivankokan what should I change?

Comment: Please, insert in your question a small document, which reproduce your problem. I have some very large examples used `ieeeaccess` and they works  as expected. BTW, your code from comment works without any warnings or errors!

Comment: @Zarko, I do not know how to do it... any help please. I am really new to this

Comment: Show the complete log-file of the small example above.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer  Still searching how to do it, give me a moment please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused as `ieeeaccess` changes the meaning of `\year`. In newer releases of `expl3`, that is covered internally. For older set ups, you can use

```latex
\let\oldyear\year
\def\year{%
  \ifdefined\pdfprimitive
    \expandafter\pdfprimitive
  \else
    \expandafter\primitive
  \fi
  \year}
\usepackage{expl3}
\let\year\oldyear
```

Comment: it worked, thank you so much!